# Affine varieties are varieties (using the definition the diagonal is closed in the product $X\times X$)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

This is a Lemma proved in [Gathmann's notes](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2014/chapter-5.pdf). There is a part I am confused with.

Here is the definition of Varieties:

> **Definition 5.19** A prevariety $X$ is called a variety (or separated) if the diagonal
>   $$\Delta_X=\{(x,x): x\in X\}$$
>   is closed in $X\times X$.

It is then followed by Lemma 5.20:

> **Lemma 5.20** (a) Affine varieties are varieties.

The proof is very simple:
If $X\subset\mathbb{A}^n$, then $\Delta_X=V\{x_1-y_1,\dots, x_n-y_n\}\subset X\times X$, where $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and $y_1,\dots,y_n$ are the coordinates on the two factors, respectively. Hence $\Delta_X$ is closed.

**My question** is, in this proof, where does the author used the fact that $X$ is an affine variety? If $X$ is only a prevariety, wouldn't the same argument work? Since we can still define the set $\Delta_X=V\{x_1-y_1,\dots, x_n-y_n\}$ which is still a closed set? I know I must be wrong, but couldn't find where.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: He does not use that $X$ is a variety but that it is affine, i.e. a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Thank you for your reply! So "affine" means a closed subset? I didn't remember that. But also, does it matter whether $X$ is closed? The definition only said $\Delta_X$ is closed in $X\times X$. Doesn't it mean as long as $\Delta_X$ is closed, it is considered to be closed in the subspace topology?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Sorry I edited. I meant "affine variety".

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking now.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Sorry if my question is confusing. I don't know why $X$ has to be closed to imply the set $\Delta_X$ is closed. I think if $\Delta_X$ can be written as zero loci of polynomials, it is already closed, whether $X$ is or not.

Comment: Which polynomials would the diagonal be the zeroes of?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I think, $x_1-y_1,\dots, x_n-y_n$.

Comment: What do those mean when $X$ is not an affine variety?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: For example, if $X=[-1,1]$, then these will be the diagonal line of the square. Isn't it closed because it is the intersection of the whole diagonal line of $\mathbb{A}^1\times \mathbb{A}^1$ (which is closed) and $X\times X$?

Comment: No, I mean what does $x_i$ and $y_i$ mean for some arbitrary $X$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Do you mean that $X$ could be in a space that is not defined normally using coordinates? If that's what you meant, does the proof work for any subsets in $\mathbb{A}^n$?

Comment: Even for some subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$, what would the $x_i$ and $y_i$ be?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I reread the chapter and found that when $X$ is a prevariety, the coordinates are not well-defined. One example is the gluing of $\mathbb{A}^1$ and $\mathbb{A}^1$ which end up with "two zeros". In that case, the coordinate at zero is not well-defined. Thank you very much for the questions! They clarify a lot.